# A tempting path for many

Tags: riddle, word, homonym

When I call, few resist.

The way is secured.

You can find your living,
Mark your time,
Or lose your liver.

Though I can glitter, I am not just gold.

What am I?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you

> A bar

When I call, few resist.

> To be called to the bar in law

The way is secured.

> To Bar Entry

You can find your living,

> As a bar tender

Mark your time,

> A measure of time in music.

Or lose your liver.

> Too much drinking in the bar

Though I can glitter, I am not just gold.

> Gold Bar, Sliver, Steel

Comment: Another alcoholic answer? :P

Comment: This is it, but you're missing a few explanations for the clues. #3 is right, but there's another to go with it, and #4 is off-key (hint hint) :P

Comment: @dedwards Bar as in music, then? That was a bad pun.

Comment: Yup, bar as in music.... obvious in hindsite.

Comment: Yeah, Bar as in music.

Answer (score 9):

Obviously the answer is

> Pokémon Go!

When I call, few resist.

> Everyone is playing it. It's [breaking records](http://www.cnbc.com/2016/07/13/pokemon-go-now-the-biggest-mobile-game-in-us-history.html)

The way is secured.

> The game is built around gps and mapping data, and may even implement navigation functionality like its predecessor, Ingress, thus "securing" the "way" to Pokéstops and gyms.

You can find your living,

> There's already people [making a living](http://gothamist.com/2016/07/12/pokemon_go_trainer_for_hire.php) on playing the game.

Mark your time,

> The game keeps track of all the time you spend and exactly when every event in the game was, so whether you intend to or not, your time is being "marked"

Or lose your liver.

> Because the app tracks location and tends to lead people to specific locations, there have already been [reports](https://nypost.com/2016/07/10/pokemon-go-is-getting-creepy/) of crimes committed with assistance from the game. It's only a matter of time before someone loses a liver.

Though I can glitter, I am not just gold.

> Pokémon have shiny versions, though they aren't implemented in Pokémon Go, they could be. Contrary to the term, shiny Pokémon are just colored differently than the standard, and so are not "just gold" versions of themselves.

What am I?

> Pokémon Go!

Comment: " It's only a matter of time before someone loses a liver." I doubt this is that guaranteed. :P made me laugh though.

Answer (score 7):

My guess is

> a College Degree

When I call, few resist.

> Most High School Graduates go on to college instead of entering the workforce directly

The way is secured

> By getting one, one sets themselves up for better employment opportunities

You can find your living,

> People typically figure out what they want to do with their lives in college

Mark your time,

> Some people just put in their 4 years, get their degree, and don't really learn anything

Or lose your liver.

> College drinking - pretty self explanatory

Though I can glitter, I am not just gold.

> This one I'm not fully sure on.  Maybe school colors? or Embellishment on the diploma itself?

Comment: Wow! That is not an option I thought of. That last line gets you though. Great try, but not correct.

Comment: For the last one: Just because you have a degree (glitter) don't expect everything to be handed to you / instant wealth (gold)!

Answer (score 5):

I believe it may be

> bathroom stall

Explanation:

When I call, few resist.

> Nature calls in the bathroom

The way is secured.

> Lock the door/stall

You can find your living,

> Janitors work in restrooms

Mark your time,

> Sometimes I waste time daydreaming in bathroom

Or lose your liver.

> Vomit in toilet (unsure)

Though I can glitter, I am not just gold.

> Golden throne = toilet

What am I?

Comment: Sorry, Paul, but this is not correct. Mark your time != waste time, and the line about the liver is way off. I did like the bit about nature calls, though.

Answer (score 5):

Could the answer be

> Booty

When I call, few resist.

> Booty Call

The way is secured.

{Needs work}

You can find your living,

> Pirate

Mark your time,

{Needs Work}

Or lose your liver.

> Pirates can drink too much rum

Though I can glitter, I am not just gold.

> Booty (treasure) can contain precious jewels and other treasure as well as gold

I realise my answer is not complete but I think it fits very well with the some of the clues and also makes use of homonyms that most  answers are ignoring

Comment: Oh ho, no, me hearty! +1 for pirate though.

Comment: Upvoting for the boo. ty.

Answer (score 3):

My thought was

> Siren

When I call few resist

> The mythological siren called sailors to their doom

The way is secured.

> Odysseus avoided the siren by securing himself to the mast of his ship

You can find your living,
Mark your time,
Or lose your liver.

> Sirens were used at the work place at punch out time and as a final call at some bars.

Though I can glitter, I am not just gold.

> police sirens have shiny lights? (I know I'm reaching on that one)

Comment: Haha! This is a fantastic answer (NPI). Unfortunately, it's not right

Answer (score 2):

Is the answer

> alcohol?

When I call, few resist.

> Many adults just need a glass of wine now and then.

The way is secured.

> Not sure about this one.

You can find your living,

> A winery?

Mark your time,
Or lose your liver.

> Excessive drinking is harmful to your liver.

Though I can glitter, I am not just gold.

> Light glinting off of the liquid, and not all alcohol is gold-colored

Comment: Good try, but you're missing a few key clues.

Comment: @Dedwards Does that mean that I got it right, I just need those other clues?

Comment: No, this isn't right, but you picked one of the wrong answers I figured people might guess.

Answer (score 2):

How about...

> ...a cell phone?

When I call, few resist.

> Most people will take a look when they hear a text message notification noise, even if they're in the middle of something.

The way is secured.

> Cell phones are password-protected.

You can find your living,

> Phone interviews and online job ads are a common thing these days.

Mark your time,

> Cell phones are equipped with clocks and can get stop-watch apps.

Or lose your liver.

> Call your friends for a night out and you might drink too much alcohol, which is bad for your liver. Also, there's [an app for that](http://www.apple.com/newsroom/2016/07/apple-and-donate-life-america-bring-organ-donation-to-iphone.html).

Though I can glitter, I am not just gold.

> Many cell phones are silver, some are gold. They come in many colors, but the current trend is shiny metallic.

Answer (score 1):

If Mithrandir's answer is wrong, this probably is too, but I figure it's worth a shot.

Is it

> Tequila?

When I call, few resist.

> Most people enjoy drinking alcohol, and tequila is a popular type of alcohol.

The way is secured.

> Could be referring to tequila being considered better tasting than some other hard liquors.

You can find your living,

> Not sure about this one.

Mark your time,
Or lose your liver.

> Alcohol damages your liver, especially when a lot is consumed over a long period of time.

Though I can glitter, I am not just gold.

> There are many types of tequila, one being gold.

Comment: Since your answer is basically sort of a sub-answer of mine... :P

Comment: Sorry, but no, this isn't right either. You're about as warm as @Mithrandir is. Good work with the "gold" line though. Made me chuckle.

Comment: @Mithrandir So hard not to think of something within that vein with the 'lose your liver' line! Banging my head against the wall trying to think of what else that line could refer to.

Comment: @Svaloq `Liver failure can result from any type of liver disorder, including viral hepatitis (most commonly hepatitis B), cirrhosis, and liver damage from alcohol or drugs such as acetaminophen. A large portion of the liver must be damaged before liver failure occurs.` -Google

Comment: @Mithrandir I guess I should say "Banging my head against the wall trying to think of what else that line could refer to that also seems to fit well with any of the other lines."

Answer (score 1):

**[CONFIRMED WRONG ANSWER]** I don't have a particular answer, but I have a feeling it might have to do with..

> money, gambling and debt.

---

*When I call, few resist.*

> This one is difficult, because while it seems like a lot of people have gambled, not many are addicted. (See [link](http://gambling.addictionblog.org/how-many-people-gamble/).)

*The way is secured.*

> This may be referring to online gambling, where one expects to be connecting to the website or server over a secure connection. (Such as [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) for a website.)

*You can find your living,
Mark your time,
Or lose your liver.*

> I think this is referring to being in debt. You can either be making a good enough living to be able to repay your debt by when it's due, or you will have to find a different way to pay the debt back, such as by selling non-essential body parts.

*Though I can glitter, I am not just gold.*

> Right now I am not sure what exactly this is referring to, but it follows the theme of money and gambling.

Comment: A creative answer that satisfies most of the clues, but it's not the one I was thinking of.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it to be

> love

Explanation:

> - You can not reset true love
>  - If you are in love, your feelings are more secure
>  - If you love someone, you always feel alive
>  - You must move for the one you love as time passes by or you will slowly wither because you were too scared to go for what you want
>  - Though love is bliss and happiness, it has its troubles

Comment: Hi April, good guess, but it's not right, either. Try to format your answer like the ones above: using the spoiler tag to suggest why your answer is right by each clue.

Comment: Or you could accept the edit that I suggested, which will fix your formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Might it be

> the Sun/Sunlight

When I call, few resist.

> Not sure about this one. People love to sit and watch the sunset/sunrise?

The way is secured.

> While it appears to move, the Sun is a stationary object. Therefore, it is securely in place.

You can find your living,

> The Sun brings life to plants and the like which in turn brings life to herbivores which in turns brings life to carnivores.

Mark your time,

> We use it to mark the time.

Or lose your liver.

> (Bit of a stretch) Liver cancer?

Though I can glitter, I am not just gold.

> Sunlight can "glitter" off of liquid surfaces and while it can be golden in appearance, it is often orange, yellow or red.

Comment: You're getting colder. Sorry, this isn't correct either. I'm not sure how one would get liver cancer from the sun. :P

Comment: @Dedwards I wasn't either, but you'd certainly lose your liver because of it (at least part of it). Because of the cancer that is.

Comment: Actually, the sun is moving - very quickly. The entire galaxy is spinning.